# Running make in Cygwin does... nothing?

Tags: gcc, makefile, cygwin

I'm trying to build gcc-7.1.0 locally on Windows via Cygwin (I already have gcc 5.4.0 installed and functioning). I downloaded the tar, ran the `configure` program in its own directory as prescribed, which yielded:

```
~/build-gcc
$ ll
total 609
-rw-r--r-- 1 Barry None  31021 Aug 12 09:08 config.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Barry None  33630 Aug 12 09:08 config.status
-rw-r--r-- 1 Barry None 551897 Aug 12 09:08 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 Barry None     13 Aug 12 09:08 serdep.tmp
```

Great, now:

```
$ make -j4
$
```

Nothing.

```
$ make --version
$
```

Nothing again.

```
$ which make
/usr/bin/make

$ cygcheck -c make
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
make                 4.2.1-2        OK
```

So it exists at least. And trying to reinstall make via cygwin suggests that everything is up to date. What's going wrong here?

Comment: You must follow the standard gcc build instructions, including making a new build directory and running configure script there.  You can choose between the download_prerequisites script or, better, install those prerequisites from cygwin menu  paying attention to options used by others.

Comment: @tim18 Did you read the 2nd sentence of the question?

Comment: Are you saying you didn't try the standard gcc instructions about running configure in a clean directory and installing mpfr, mpc, gmp?  Easier to start by installing gcc 6.3 and referring to a successful set of configure options.

Comment: run `strace make --help` to identify which dll is causing problem and need to be reinstalled. Probably you updated cygwin without closing all programs and one of the dll was not correctly updated.

Comment: @tim18 Do you see where it says in the question that I ran configure in a clean directory?

Comment: @matzeri Yeah that did it - uninstalled and reinstalled `make` and then everything worked.